# Boost Security_review compatibility

Tags: security, caching

I had [security_review](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review) warning for [boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) cache folder.

I've changed cache folder location to "sites/default/files/cache"

And now I have no warning.

Is this solution correct and safe?

Comment: Insofar as the security review module's checklist is concerned, yes. If you no longer see a warning it means you've fixed the problem as far as that module is concerned

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the Boost module, it should be safe as well. Make sure you also regenerate the .htaccess for your site.